# Response.Redirect weird behavior in IE 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1

Here is the scenario where I'm using Response.Redirect..

Base website calling a SSO using httpwebrequest to third party website - Get a key.
Once base website get's the key - base website redirects the client browser to the third party website with the key.

Weird thing:

Let's say the website URL is like this http://basewebsite/SSO/ThridpartySSO.aspx
The third party ***redirect*** URL is http://thirdparty/Incoming/IncomingSSO.aspx?key=ASFDSFWERASDFASDF

After doing the httpwebrequest and getting the key all I'm doing is

```
Response.Redirect("http://thirdparty/Incoming/IncomingSSO.aspx?key=" + key);
```

It works all the time in all browsers, except in IE8, very sporadic, I get page cannot be displayed with a URL like this

**http://basewebsite/***Incoming/IncomingSSO.aspx?key=ASFDSFWERASDFASDF*

Notice that the domain name in the above URL is base website's .. but the rest of the URL is third party website's.

Can't figure out why, Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following

```
Response.Redirect("your third party url", false);
```

it Redirects a client to a new URL. Specifies the new URL and whether execution of the current page should terminate.

Comment: Try using it with "true" as second parameter as you are sending request to another website and if you are doing it permanently and if you are using .NET 4.0 then try Response.RedirectPermanent() method